# Faster than the speed of light

Tags: speed-of-light, velocity, vectors, coordinate-systems, faster-than-light

Could I ask a question about light?

Let's say light travels at a $45^{\circ}$ angle, so the vector velocity would be (c, c) i.e. travels c on the *x* axis and c on the *y* axis. Then wouldn't the hypotenuse be $\sqrt{2c^{2}},$ which is $\sqrt{2} c$, which is just a little faster than the speed of light, which is impossible? Am I missing something?

Comment: No, officer, I wasn't traveling at 84mph in the eastbound lane!  I was only traveling 60mph northeast and 60 mph southeast!

Comment: What stops you from changing the coordinate system to align with the light beam (rotate by 45°)? The components of the velocity vector in the new coordinate system is now below $c$, while the absolute value is $c$ and all is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Light travels at $c$ along the direction it is travelling. Looking at the figure, in one second it moves a distance $c \times 1 = c$ along the solid black line. It doesn't move this full distance when you look at how far it moves along the dotted lines. In fact, along the blue line it only moves a distance $c \sin \theta$ while along the red line it only moves a distance $c \cos \theta$. The speed along the black line is found from Pythagoras's theorem $$\text{speed} = \sqrt{(c \sin \theta)^2 + (c \cos \theta)^2 } = c,$$ as it should be.    [image]

Answer (score 2):

If light travels at an angle of $45$ degrees, then the vector velocity is $(c\cos\theta,c\sin\theta)$, whose resultant is $c$ (You can check that out).

Comment: Right, I understand it now, the parameters I gave for the components would lead to a nonsensical result, so you must use the hypotenuse, or c, to find the components, not the other way around like I was asking.

The only way my question would make sense is if for example it were referring to the hypothetical tachyon, which goes faster than light.

Apologies for the brain fart. Don't make my mistakes.

Comment: @PlanetAstro_William If you think that this answer helped you, then please accept it.

Comment: It did help in understanding the mathematics, but in terms of it actually being an answer, it doesn't really explain why the components can't be used to find the real velocity. If no one can give a better answer soon, I'll accept yours, no worries.